# C: printf with typedef unsigned long long int

Tags: c, printf, typedef

I have a typedef that contains a 64bit memory address in hex, but using `%x` with `printf` is giving me the following error:

```
error: format '%x' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 4 has type 'address'\
```

This is my declaration of the typedef:

```
typedef unsigned long long int address;
```

How can I print this hexadecimal value? Thanks!

Edit: the memory address is not a pointer, I am reading hexadecimal values from another file and need to store these 64bit addresses numerically using the typedef I defined.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler tell you below what to use instead?

Comment: I think you should use `"%p"` for pointer, because you need to print the address right?!

Comment: `typedef unsigned long long int address;` where address means "pointer"?  That's what `[u]intptr_t` is for.

Comment: @JohnBode using %llx, %08x, %p gives the sequential results: (24fe48, 0024fe48 and 000000000024FE48)

Comment: address is not a pointer in my case. I am reading addresses from a file and storing them as an unsigned 64 bit memory address. I simply created a typedef for it called "address"

Comment: *Edit: memory address is not a pointer* - led my answer -5 downvotes

Comment: @LinuXMan: Type matters.  `%p` expects an argument of type `void *`.  `%x` expects an argument of type `unsigned int`.  For `unsigned long long`, you need to use `%llx`, otherwise the behavior is undefined (which means you *may* get the output you expect, but i5 isn’t guaranteed).

Comment: @JohnBode the llx's output is still the same, don't know why.

Comment: @LinuXMan: One of the possible outcomes of undefined behavior is your code appears to work as expected.  It’s still undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%x` conversion specifier expects its corresponding argument to have type `unsigned int`.  To print an `unsigned long long`, you need to use the length modifier `ll`, or `%llx`.

**Handy Table**

```
Length Modifier        Type
–––––––––––––––        ––––
             ll        (unsigned) long long
              l        (unsigned) long
              h        (unsigned) short
             hh        (unsigned) char
              j        intmax_t, uintmax_t
              z        size_t
              t        ptrdiff_t
              L        long double
```

So to format an `unsigned char` value as hex, you’d use `%hhx` or `%hhX`.  To format a `short` as decimal, you’d use `%hd`.  To format an `unsigned long` as octal, you’d use `%lo`.

**Gratuitous rant**

You’ve just illustrated why I tend to avoid using the `typedef` facility for primitive types.

You’ve created what’s known as a *leaky abstraction* - you’ve ostensibly created a new type to represent an address value, but you have to know that it has been implemented as an `unsigned long long` in order to use it correctly.

If you’re going to create an abstract type, you need to go all the way and create abstractions (functions, macros, etc.) for all operations on that type, including input and output (and assignment, and validation, etc.).

It’s generally not worth the effort for primitive types, so I’d avoid using `typedef` for this purpose.